# Why is stdout printing out an empty string in this case?

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, stdout

I am reading about subprocess and playing around with some code.
I'm using Windows 7 with Python3.6

```
import subprocess


process = subprocess.Popen(['notepad', 'C:\\Users\Amit\Downloads\InsiderTrades.txt'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
#I'm opening a text file which has a list of stock tickers

stdout1, stderr1 = process.communicate()
print(stdout1.decode('ASCII'))
```

The output I'm getting is nothing or

`b''` as the value for stdout1.

I"m not quite sure what `communicate` is outputting in this case. 
I was under the impression that it would output the text from my text file or it would output anything I type into the text file.

I tried typing into the newly opened text file as well, but I'm still getting the same output , `b''`

So what am I getting an empty string, despite typing something into the newly opened textfile.

Comment: If you type that command in a cmd console, it opens notepad and prints nothing. That's the same here.

Comment: Not clear what you're expecting this do  but notepad just doesn't really take its inputs from stdin nor does it output to stdout. It's a GUI program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subprocess is basically as if you run that command in the terminal.

So what you are doing is running
`notepad some_file.txt`
which just opens a file in notepad, but it doesn't send anything to standard output.

If you run a command that writes something to standard output, then you will have a non-empty stdout1. Try `ls` for example if you are on a *nix system or `dir` if on Windows.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I will make an attempt with  'dir' as I'm on a Windows system.

Comment: Okay. It seems to work with `dir`. I think I'm beginning to understand how subprocess and stdin and stdout work now.